# How to add more than one relationship in the Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, relationship

I am trying to add song into multiple playlist. I am using this code below, but when I use this function it keeps overriding the old relationship with other playlist. Example, I add `SongA` to `playlist(A)` and I call this function again and add `SongA` to `playlist(B)`, the `SongA` in `playlist(A)` is gone.

```
open class func addToRelationships(_ identifier : String, playlistName : String){
    print("Adding Relationship to the Song and the Playlist")  
    let selectedPlaylist = getPlaylist(playlistName)
    let selectedSong = getSong(identifier)
    //add song reference to songs relationship (in playlist entity)
    let playlist = selectedPlaylist.mutableSetValue(forKey: "songs")
    playlist.add(selectedSong)
    //add playlist reference to p laylists relationship (in song entity)
    let inPlaylists = selectedSong.mutableSetValue(forKey: "playlists")
    inPlaylists.add(selectedPlaylist) 
    save()
}
```

I am currently using this for the Core Data.

[image: Data Model]

Comment: If you have set up the inverse relationship (which it appears you have done) then song to the playlist should be sufficient. Core Data will manage the inverse and add the relevant playlist to the Song object.

Comment: You answered my question, i forgot to set inverse relationship. :)